# How to import a local package with Python on Windows?

Tags: python, anaconda, pythonpath, mako

I would like to use `mako-render` from the package *mako*.

Consider these 3 files:

D:\test.py

```
from module import foo
print(foo())
```

D:\test.txt

```
<%! from module import foo %>
${foo()}
```

D:\test\module.py

```
def foo():
    return 42
```

If I want to execute `foo.py` I need to add `D:\test` to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
d:\>C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'

d:\>set PYTHONPATH=D:\test;%PYTHONPATH%

d:\>C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe test.py
42
```

However things are different with `mako-render`. On POSIX systems `mako-render` is just a script that calls Python under the hood. On Windows it is an executable `mako-render.exe`. So if I do the same, it doesn't work:

```
d:\>C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\mako-render.exe test.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Mako-1.0.7-py3.6.egg\mako\cmd.py", line 55, in cmdline
    template = Template(filename=filename, lookup=lookup)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Mako-1.0.7-py3.6.egg\mako\template.py", line 338, in __init__
    module = self._compile_from_file(path, filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Mako-1.0.7-py3.6.egg\mako\template.py", line 416, in _compile_from_file
    filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Mako-1.0.7-py3.6.egg\mako\template.py", line 714, in _compile_text
    exec(code, module.__dict__, module.__dict__)
  File "test_txt", line 16, in <module>

ImportError: cannot import name 'foo'
```

How does it work on Windows?

If I copy from Linux `mako-render` to `D:\my-mako-render`, I can do:

```
d:\>C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -m my-mako-render test.txt
42

42
```

So the problem appear with the `.exe` files.

Comment: Why importing from `test`? As I see the definition of `foo` is in `test.module`. Can you try `from test.module import foo` instead?

Comment: My mistake, copy/paste errors